# how to click on textarea to activate them with javascript

Tags: javascript, webkit, click, textarea

I want activate textarea like on facebook wall. I was tried .focus() but not working. Is there any way to click on it with javascript or visualbasic ?

Answer (score 2):

check this example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#text_area_id").focus();
});
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/or9400/6w7ggbe9/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

   window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("textArea").focus();
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
      <input type="textarea"  id="textArea">
    </form>
<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language='javascript'>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
         $("#result").html("Click Now");
        $('#tarea').focus(function(){
              $("#result").html("Textarea Clicked");
          });
      });  
  </script>
 <body>
   <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id='tarea'></textarea>
   
   <p id='result'></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementById('textAreaId').focus();` should work.

If you want the textarea to be focused when the page loads you could add an `autofocus` attribute to the html element as well

Comment: it's not working :( beocause i try execute javascript in webkit .net  browser